# fortran code does not compile after system update on macbook

Tags: macos, system, gfortran, macos-catalina

```
amtssk@DEVICE PERT % make
/usr/local/bin/gfortran-11 -fno-backslash -Wall -Wno-tabs -O -m64 -o pert objects/main.o objects/start.o objects/metric.o objects/march.o objects/mar1d.o objects/usrpq.o objects/bound.o objects/flux.o objects/plot.o objects/rwmodel.o objects/utilities.o objects/vsr.o objects/usr.o objects/myio.o  -L /Users/amtssk/OneDrive - University of Leeds/oldmac/Computing/Serial/pgplot -lpgplot -lpng -lz -L/usr/X11R6/lib -lX11
gfortran-11: error: -E or -x required when input is from standard input
make: *** [pert] Error 1
```

Comment: Most likely place to look `-L /Users/amtssk/OneDrive - University of Leeds/oldmac/Computing/Serial/pgplot` as here the `-L` command does look like to have an unquoted / unescaped path with spaces.

Answer (score 0):

I have found the reason - the very unfortunate name for the corporate OneDrive folder, OneDrive - University of Leeds. It was quoted in the relevant path variable but became unquoted when passed to the compiler.  Thank you Albert, I have just noticed you pinpointing this too!